# How can i wrap php code in one echo

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, string

I have php code and some html  i want my all html to be wrapped in echo ("") for the ajax respones.
please help

please help
here is my code

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['getcart'])){

    $cart_item_query="SELECT * FROM cart";
    $cart_item_run = mysqli_query($conn,$cart_item_query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($cart_item_run)>0){
        $grand_total=0;
        while($cart_row=mysqli_fetch_array($cart_item_run)){
            $pro_id = $cart_row['product_id'];
            $pro_qty = $cart_row['qty'];

                       $product_query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id'";
            $product_run = mysqli_query($conn, $product_query);
            $product_row = mysqli_fetch_array($product_run);
            $pro_name = $product_row['product_name'];
            $pro_image = $product_row['product_image'];
            $pro_sell_price = $product_row['sell_price'];
            $total = $pro_sell_price*$pro_qty;
            $grand_total =$grand_total+ $total;


            ?>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><img src="img/<?php echo $pro_image; ?>" alt="" width="50px"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><p><?php echo $pro_name; ?></p><a href=""><p><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</p></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <select class="change_qty" size="1" style="width:50px;">
                        <?
                            for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
                                $selected = $pro_qty == $i? 'selected' : '';
                                echo "<option class='qty' data-pro='{$pro_id}' value='{$i}' {$selected}>{$i}</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><input data-pro="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" id="price-<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $pro_sell_price; ?>" disabled class="form-control dis-input price"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><input id="total-<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" data-pro="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" disabled class="form-control dis-input total"></div>

            </div>

            <hr>

            <?

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why? Leaving php and writing html is the same as echoing html from php.

Comment: No need to echo the response just use ajax it self to set the innerHTML.

Comment: actually this is in action page .i need to display it on cart page so in ajax i will receive response so that response i can set to innerHTML  of a div which is in cart page. now it is displaying it on action page itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save the output in a php var and echo it once done. If you just want to output it as html in some DOM it's not necessary to do this (like others described above).
`

```
$cart_item_query="SELECT * FROM cart";
$cart_item_run = mysqli_query($conn,$cart_item_query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($cart_item_run)>0){
    $grand_total=0;
    while($cart_row=mysqli_fetch_array($cart_item_run)){
        $pro_id = $cart_row['product_id'];
        $pro_qty = $cart_row['qty'];

                   $product_query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id'";
        $product_run = mysqli_query($conn, $product_query);
        $product_row = mysqli_fetch_array($product_run);
        $pro_name = $product_row['product_name'];
        $pro_image = $product_row['product_image'];
        $pro_sell_price = $product_row['sell_price'];
        $total = $pro_sell_price*$pro_qty;
        $grand_total =$grand_total+ $total;




        $return_value = "<div class=\"row\">

            <div class=\"col-md-3 col-xs-3\"><img src=\"img/".$pro_image."\" alt=\"\" width=\"50px\"></div>
            <div class=\"col-md-3 col-xs-3\"><p>".$pro_name."</p><a href=\"\"><p><i class=\"fa fa-trash\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Remove</p></a></div>
            <div class=\"col-md-2 col-xs-2\">
                <select class=\"change_qty\" size=\"1\" style=\"width:50px;\">";

                        for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
                            $selected = $pro_qty == $i? 'selected' : '';
                            $return_value .= "<option class=\"qty\" data-pro=\"".$pro_id."\" value=\"".$i."\" ".$selected.">".$i."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                $return_value .= "</select>
            </div>

            <div class=\"col-md-2 col-xs-2\"><input data-pro=\"".$pro_id."\" id=\"price-".$pro_id."\" type=\"text\" value=\"".$pro_sell_price."\" disabled class=\"form-control dis-input price\"></div>
            <div class=\"col-md-2 col-xs-2\"><input id=\"total-".$pro_id."\" data-pro=\"".$pro_id."\" type=\"text\" value=\"".$total."\" disabled class=\"form-control dis-input total\"></div>

        </div>

        <hr>";



    }
}
echo $return_value;
```

}
?>`

Comment: Sir , this solved my a problem but now arise one more problem here. in this code you can see there is a class name change_qty to selectbox... in js when i try to give a event handler (.change) it doesnt recognise this class.where could be the issue?

Comment: in above example it echo $return_value one variable ..... the question is can i echo more than one variables ? if yes then how can i receive them in ajax response separately and display them in different divs.

Comment: @kohali this is because you probably assign the listener on page load directly. assign the listener like `$(document).on('change','.change_qty',function(){ your code });`

Comment: You can use json_encode like so 
`$arr_with_all_return_values[] =array('msg' => 'your message');
$arr_with_all_return_values[] = array('something_else_to_return'=>'what else needs to be returned you ask?');
$arr_with_all_return_values[] = array('return_value'=>$return_value);
echo json_encode($arr_with_all_return_values);`